# Empty the_content for all posts

Tags: custom-field, the-content

I'm moving everything that is displayed with the_content in custom fields and i want to remove/emtpy the content of the post_content column in the database, for every post.

Is there a mysql query that does that or another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UPDATE`wp_posts`SET`post_content`="" WHERE 1`

Comment: That works. I needed to do this only for the default post type so i run `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content="" WHERE post_type='post'`. Thank you.